# Cannot find module '@vitejs/plugin-react' or its corresponding type

Tags: typescript, vite

I have created the project using `npm create vite@latest` and I choose ts-react, when I ran the script the
`npm run dev` worked, no warning however, I am getting an `Cannot find module '@vitejs/plugin-react' or its corresponding type` in vite.config.ts in vs code.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb9na.png)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try to restart your VSCode editor

Comment: Yes, I reopened the browser next morning, and the problems were fixed,

Answer (score 14):

Restart your TS Server following these steps:

1. Open Command Palette: `Command` + `Shift` + `P`.
2. Search `TypeScript: Restart TS server`.
3. Press `Enter`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the issue. 

Please update the top answer to include all cases that might solve the issue

Answer (score 8):

**If you are using SWC!**

---

Use **`"@vitejs/plugin-react-swc"`**, instead of `"@vitejs/plugin-react"`.

Comment: That was my case, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was that I forgot to run **yarn** in terminal ( or **npm install** if you use npm) just after initial creation of project ( npm create vite@latest or yarn create vite ).
Because vite needs to install all dependencies in package.json and create node_modules folder

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was that I forgot to install types:

`$ npm i -D @types/node`

Answer (score 3):

> Cannot find module '@vitejs/plugin-react' or its corresponding type

The question itself is hinting what the issue is. You need to install '@vitejs/plugin-react'. For some reason it doesn't get included when you create a vite project.

If you're using yarn

```
yarn add @vitejs/plugin-react
```

if you're using npm

```
npm i -S @vitejs/plugin-react
```

Comment: Yep, this was my problem.  I just assumed it would be added when I installed Vite.  Don't forget to add `vite.config.js` as well!

Answer (score -1):

Adding "types": ["vite"] in my tsconfig.json file worked for me.